# creating a object of a class using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have form data which i am trying to post to the server i am using ajax as i have the form as a partial on the page. I have a class that has these parameters which is the "EditModel" class in C# on the server.

How would i convert this to these variables to this model object so that i can pass the data though, this model has to be created using javascript

```
 function getFromData() {
           //alert("hell yea");
           var username = document.getElementById("Name").value;
           var pa = document.getElementById("password").value;
           var email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
           var active = document.getElementById("IsActive").value;

       }
```

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: because the class is on a sever c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a json object to hold the post data before sending it across. Here's an example using jQuery to make the ajax call itself:

```
var $form = $('#container').find('form'); // this will find the first form element within the element with id of container
var ajaxData = {
    'name': $form.find('#Name').val(),
    'password': $form.find('#password').val(),
    'email': $form.find('#Email').val(),
    'isActive': $form.find('#IsActive').val()
};
$.ajax({
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    type: 'POST',
    data: ajaxData,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (data.redirect) {
            window.location.href = data.redirect;
        } else {
            alert("Something bad happened");
        }
    }
});
```

You can make the action method on the server side return some json (via a `JsonResult`) and check for the presence of that json in the success method of the ajax call. If the json is present, the POST was successful and you can redirect appropriately. I pass a URL in a property called redirect, which I then use to redirect the user to a success screen.

Comment: in the do somthing would i call the method which i have created